# ConvertAll Methods Implementation for Jagged Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, array, generics, converting, lambda

This is a follow-up question for [ConvertAll Methods Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/255269/231235) and [ConvertAll Methods Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C# - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/255395/231235). Besides the multidimensional array (`[,]`, `[,,]`, `[,,,]`...) case, I am trying to implement another series overloading methods to deal with jagged arrays in C#.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation is as below.

```
class Converters
{
    public static TOutput[][] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[][] inputs, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (inputs is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
        }

        if (converter is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
        }

        TOutput[][] output = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, dim1 => Array.ConvertAll(dim1, dim2 => converter(dim2)));
        return output;
    }

    public static TOutput[][][] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[][][] inputs, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (inputs is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
        }

        if (converter is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
        }

        TOutput[][][] output = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, dim1 => 
                               Array.ConvertAll(dim1, dim2 => 
                               Array.ConvertAll(dim2, dim3 => converter(dim3)
                               )));
        return output;
    }

    public static TOutput[][][][] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[][][][] inputs, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (inputs is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
        }

        if (converter is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
        }

        TOutput[][][][] output = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, dim1 =>
                                 Array.ConvertAll(dim1, dim2 =>
                                 Array.ConvertAll(dim2, dim3 => 
                                 Array.ConvertAll(dim3, dim4 => converter(dim4)
                                 ))));
        return output;
    }

    public static TOutput[][][][][] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[][][][][] inputs, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (inputs is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
        }

        if (converter is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
        }

        TOutput[][][][][] output = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, dim1 =>
                                   Array.ConvertAll(dim1, dim2 =>
                                   Array.ConvertAll(dim2, dim3 =>
                                   Array.ConvertAll(dim3, dim4 => 
                                   Array.ConvertAll(dim4, dim5 => converter(dim5)
                                   )))));
        return output;
    }

    public static TOutput[][][][][][] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[][][][][][] inputs, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (inputs is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
        }

        if (converter is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
        }

        TOutput[][][][][][] output = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, dim1 =>
                                     Array.ConvertAll(dim1, dim2 =>
                                     Array.ConvertAll(dim2, dim3 =>
                                     Array.ConvertAll(dim3, dim4 =>
                                     Array.ConvertAll(dim4, dim5 => 
                                     Array.ConvertAll(dim5, dim6 => converter(dim6)
                                     ))))));
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

The test cases listed here include array of arrays, array of arrays of arrays and array of arrays of arrays of arrays.

```
//    Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-jagged-arrays/

Console.WriteLine("Jagged Array [][]");
Console.WriteLine();

int[][] jagged_arr = new int[][] 
{
    new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4},
    new int[] {11, 34, 67},
    new int[] {89, 23},
    new int[] {0, 45, 78, 53, 99}
};

double[][] output1 = Converters.ConvertAll(jagged_arr, x => x + 0.1);

for (int dim1 = 0; dim1 < output1.Length; dim1++)
{
    for (int dim2 = 0; dim2 < output1[dim1].GetLength(0); dim2++)
    {
        Console.Write($"[{dim1}][{dim2}]: {output1[dim1][dim2]}\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Jagged Array [][][]");
Console.WriteLine();

int[][][] jagged_arr2 = new int[][][]
{
    jagged_arr,
    jagged_arr,
    jagged_arr,
    jagged_arr
};

double[][][] output2 = Converters.ConvertAll(jagged_arr2, x => x + 0.1);

for (int dim1 = 0; dim1 < output2.Length; dim1++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"dim1 = {dim1}");
    for (int dim2 = 0; dim2 < output2[dim1].GetLength(0); dim2++)
    {
        for (int dim3 = 0; dim3 < output2[dim1][dim2].GetLength(0); dim3++)
        {
            Console.Write($"[{dim2}][{dim3}]: {output2[dim1][dim2][dim3]}\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Jagged Array [][][][]");
Console.WriteLine();

int[][][][] jagged_arr3 = new int[][][][]
{
    jagged_arr2,
    jagged_arr2,
    jagged_arr2,
    jagged_arr2
};

double[][][][] output3 = Converters.ConvertAll(jagged_arr3, x => x + 0.1);

for (int dim1 = 0; dim1 < output3.Length; dim1++)
{
    for (int dim2 = 0; dim2 < output3[dim1].GetLength(0); dim2++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"dim1 = {dim1}, dim2 = {dim2}");
        for (int dim3 = 0; dim3 < output3[dim1][dim2].GetLength(0); dim3++)
        {
            for (int dim4 = 0; dim4 < output3[dim1][dim2][dim3].GetLength(0); dim4++)
            {
                Console.Write($"[{dim3}][{dim4}]: {output3[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4]}\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Jagged Array [][]

[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

Jagged Array [][][]

dim1 = 0
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 1
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 2
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 3
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1


Jagged Array [][][][]

dim1 = 0, dim2 = 0
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 0, dim2 = 1
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 0, dim2 = 2
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 0, dim2 = 3
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 1, dim2 = 0
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 1, dim2 = 1
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 1, dim2 = 2
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 1, dim2 = 3
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 2, dim2 = 0
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 2, dim2 = 1
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 2, dim2 = 2
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 2, dim2 = 3
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 3, dim2 = 0
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 3, dim2 = 1
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 3, dim2 = 2
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1

dim1 = 3, dim2 = 3
[0][0]: 1.1     [0][1]: 2.1     [0][2]: 3.1     [0][3]: 4.1
[1][0]: 11.1    [1][1]: 34.1    [1][2]: 67.1
[2][0]: 89.1    [2][1]: 23.1
[3][0]: 0.1     [3][1]: 45.1    [3][2]: 78.1    [3][3]: 53.1    [3][4]: 99.1
```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [ConvertAll Methods Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/255269/231235) and

  [ConvertAll Methods Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C# - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/255395/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  Trying to implement another series `ConvertAll` overloading methods to deal with jagged arrays in C#.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any issue about potential drawback or unnecessary overhead of the implemented methods, please let me know.

Comment: Have you considered to use meta programming to generate the different overloads? Just like I suggested in your previous follow-up thread.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you for the comments. I know that there is a way to use meta programming to generate these overloads. Besides, I am wondering the feedback of the proposed non-metaprogramming version first.

Comment: The parameters' null checks can be shortened. Unfortunately [Simplified parameter null validation code](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145) is not yet part of the C# language. But with code weaving you can use [NullGuards](https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your end goal is to apply `ConvertAll` to all of the different types of C# arrays, nested or not, and with with lower bounds not equal to zero.

All arrays can be manipulated through the [`Array`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array) base class and any level of nesting can be handled by using recursion.

First some plumbing is needed to [enumerate all possible indices](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/c4961fbba63d3a44.html) of an array of arbitrary dimensions:

```
private static bool IncrementIndices(Array array, int[] indices)
{
    int rank = array.Rank;
    indices[rank - 1]++;
    for (int dim = rank - 1; dim >= 0; dim--)
    {
        if (indices[dim] > array.GetUpperBound(dim))
        {
            if (dim == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int j = dim; j < rank; j++)
                indices[j] = array.GetLowerBound(j);
            indices[dim - 1]++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

With this method we can then convert each value in a non-nested array:

```
public static Array ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(this Array source, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(converter, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
    }
    if (!typeof(TInput).IsAssignableFrom(source.GetType().GetElementType()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type of " + nameof(TInput) + " (" + typeof(TInput).Name + ") is not assignable from the element type of " + nameof(source) + " (" + source.GetType().GetElementType().Name + ")");
    }

    var dimensions = new int[source.Rank];
    var indices = new int[source.Rank];
    var anyDimensionZero = false;
    for (int dimension = 0; dimension < dimensions.Length; dimension++)
    {
        dimensions[dimension] = source.GetLength(dimension);
        indices[dimension] = source.GetLowerBound(dimension);
        if (dimensions[dimension] == 0)
        {
            anyDimensionZero = true;
        }
    }

    var destination = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TOutput), dimensions, indices);
    if (anyDimensionZero)
    {
        return destination;
    }

    do
    {
        var currentValue = source.GetValue(indices);
        var convertedValue = converter((TInput)currentValue);
        destination.SetValue(convertedValue, indices);
    }
    while (IncrementIndices(source, indices));

    return destination;
}
```

We can then add recursion to handle nesting:

```
public static Array ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(this Array source, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(converter, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));
    }
    var elementType = source.GetType().GetElementType();
    if (!typeof(TInput).IsAssignableFrom(source.GetType().GetElementType()) && !elementType.IsArray)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type of " + nameof(TInput) + " (" + typeof(TInput).Name + ") is not assignable from the element type of " + nameof(source) + " (" + source.GetType().GetElementType().Name + ")");
    }

    var recursivelyApplyConverter = elementType != typeof(TInput);

    var dimensions = new int[source.Rank];
    var indices = new int[source.Rank];
    var anyDimensionZero = false;
    for (int dimension = 0; dimension < dimensions.Length; dimension++)
    {
        dimensions[dimension] = source.GetLength(dimension);
        indices[dimension] = source.GetLowerBound(dimension);
        if (dimensions[dimension] == 0)
        {
            anyDimensionZero = true;
        }
    }

    var destinationElementType = recursivelyApplyConverter ? GetTargetArrayType(elementType, typeof(TOutput)) : typeof(TOutput);
    var destination = Array.CreateInstance(destinationElementType, dimensions, indices);
    if (anyDimensionZero)
    {
        return destination;
    }

    do
    {
        var currentValue = source.GetValue(indices);
        if (ReferenceEquals(currentValue, null) && recursivelyApplyConverter)
            continue;
        var convertedValue = recursivelyApplyConverter
            ? (object)ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>((Array)currentValue, converter)
            : converter((TInput)currentValue);
        destination.SetValue(convertedValue, indices);
    }
    while (IncrementIndices(source, indices));

    return destination;
}
```

Here the tricky bit is to construct the correct target type:

```
private static Type GetTargetArrayType(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
{
    var types = new Stack<Type>();
    var type = sourceType;
    while (type.IsArray && type != targetType)
    {
        types.Push(type);
        type = type.GetElementType();
    }
    var resultType = targetType;
    while (types.Count > 0)
    {
        var arrayType = types.Pop();
        var rank = arrayType.GetArrayRank();
        //MakeArrayType() != MakeArrayType(1)
        //See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makearraytype
        resultType = rank == 1 ? resultType.MakeArrayType() : resultType.MakeArrayType(rank);
    }
    return resultType;
}
```

The same basic construct can be used to implement other primitives such as foreach:

```
public static void ForEach<TSource>(this Array source, Func<TSource, int[], TSource> updater)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(updater, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(updater));
    }
    if (!typeof(TSource).IsAssignableFrom(source.GetType().GetElementType()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type of " + nameof(TSource) + " (" + typeof(TSource).Name + ") is not assignable from the element type of " + nameof(source) + " (" + source.GetType().GetElementType().Name + ")");
    }

    var indices = new int[source.Rank];
    for (int dimension = 0; dimension < indices.Length; dimension++)
    {
        if (source.GetLength(dimension) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        indices[dimension] = source.GetLowerBound(dimension);
    }

    var tempIndices = new int[indices.Length];
    do
    {
        Array.Copy(indices, tempIndices, indices.Length);
        var currentValue = source.GetValue(indices);
        var updatedValue = updater((TSource)currentValue, tempIndices);
        source.SetValue(updatedValue, indices);
    }
    while (IncrementIndices(source, indices));
}

public static void ForEach<TSource>(this Array source, Action<TSource, int[]> action)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(action, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    }
    if (!typeof(TSource).IsAssignableFrom(source.GetType().GetElementType()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type of " + nameof(TSource) + " (" + typeof(TSource).Name + ") is not assignable from the element type of " + nameof(source) + " (" + source.GetType().GetElementType().Name + ")");
    }

    var indices = new int[source.Rank];
    for (int dimension = 0; dimension < indices.Length; dimension++)
    {
        if (source.GetLength(dimension) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        indices[dimension] = source.GetLowerBound(dimension);
    }

    var tempIndices = new int[indices.Length];
    do
    {
        Array.Copy(indices, tempIndices, indices.Length);
        var currentValue = source.GetValue(indices);
        action((TSource)currentValue, tempIndices);
    }
    while (IncrementIndices(source, indices));
}
```

Now all that's left is to wrap the core ConvertAll in strongly typed wrappers, preferably in an automated way.

```
int[,][] test = (int[,][])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int[]), lengths: new int[] { 2, 2 }, lowerBounds: new int[] { -11, 10 });
int arrayLength = 1;
int valueCounter = 1;
test.ForEach(_ =>
{
    var array = new int[arrayLength++];
    array.ForEach(__ => valueCounter++);
    return array;
});

test.ConvertAll(x => x + 0.1f)
    .ForEach((l2, l1Indices) => 
        l2.ForEach((x, l2Indices) => 
            Console.WriteLine("array[{1}][{2}] = {0}", x, string.Join(", ", l1Indices), string.Join(", ", l2Indices))));

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    //All of the above
    
    public static void ForEach<TSource>(this TSource[] source, Func<TSource, TSource> updater)
    {
        ForEach<TSource>((Array)source, (x, _) => updater(x));
    }
    
    public static void ForEach<TSource>(this TSource[,] source, Func<TSource, TSource> updater)
    {
        ForEach<TSource>((Array)source, (x, _) => updater(x));
    }
    
    public static void ForEach<TSource>(this TSource[] source, Action<TSource, int[]> action)
    {
        ForEach<TSource>((Array)source, action);
    }
    
    public static void ForEach<TSource>(this TSource[,] source, Action<TSource, int[]> action)
    {
        ForEach<TSource>((Array)source, action);
    }
    
    public static TOutput[,][] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(this TInput[,][] source, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        return (TOutput[,][])ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>((Array)source, converter);
    }
}
```